# Custom View is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, custom-view, xcode-instruments

On iOS8-Xcode7.1-Swift2.1,Custom UIView is very slow.

On iOS9 is not slow.

I have checked the above things by Time Profilier.

'super.init(coder: aDecoder)' took 2 seconds.

I attached Time Profilier capture.

But i never experienced such a situation.

What is this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using custom fonts?

Comment: Yes,I'm using 'UIFont(name: "HiraKakuProN-W3", size: 14)' as for example.

Comment: Check that the font is linked properly in your info.plist and that its being added to your application target. I've had the same issue where there was no obvious reason but I mislinked a font, the iOS device tries to look for the font on the main thread and times out.

Comment: Ohhhh!Thank you.I could resolve it.

Comment: Glad to see that was the issue. Its one that's hard to find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reslove this problem by a hint of @David Wong.
Thank you.

Font list is differnt between iOS8 and iOS9.
'HiraginoSans' is available from iOS9.
If iOS8 try to use this font,device have to download at first.
That's why view load is very slow loading.

Mac has Font family on FontBook.
I could resove it by importing above font to xcode project.

Thank you.